# How to extract significant numeric digits from an alphanumeric string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an ID DIS002789.I want to extract 2789 from the given ID.I have to use the extracted number in a for loop using a variable.

I tried using re.findall.

```
inputk='DIS0002789'
non_decimal = re.findall(r'[\d.]+', inputk)
for n in range(non_decimal, non_decimal + 1000):
```

Im getting 002789. But I want my output to be 2789.And also i cant use the for loop because of this.It shows a n error saying 002789 is an invalid syntax.
I tried converting it to int. but its shows the following error,
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Convert it to integer? Or  use `lstrip`

Comment: `re.sub('^[^1-9]*', '', inputk)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ignore leading zeros and convert it to an integer to use in a loop

```
inputk='DIS0002789'
non_decimal = int(re.findall(r':?[0]*(\d+)', inputk)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the result of `re.findall(r'[\d.]+', inputk)` to `int` in order to make it an integer. `int('0123')` will ignore leading zeroes.

Example:

```
inputk='DIS0002789'
non_decimal = int(re.findall(r'[\d.]+', inputk))
```

if you want it to be a string you can pass it to `str` again: `str(int('0123')) == '123'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the int value, you should convert it to integer as other answers show. If you only want the string, you can try adding the optional leading zeros:

```
inputk='DIS0002789'
non_decimal = re.findall(r':?[0]*(\d+)', inputk)
non_decimal
```

output:

```
['2789']
```

Comment: I need to use the output in a for loop.So, I need my output to be an integer.Your solution gives me a string.Thanks for your input.